# “Preposterous” meaning directly linked to literal latin etymology?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

In common English, I understand “preposterous” to mean abusrd/ridiculous/unlikely etc.

The Latin literal translation, as I understand it, is to put something the wrong way round (such as a cart before a horse).

When we use the term “preposterous”, are we trying to imply literally that something is backwards? Or is it a more indirect meaning of simply being illogical?

I hope that question makes sense. An analogous example might be the term “regression model.” Translated literally, it means returning to a prior state. But when we have regression models in business we aren’t literally modeling something that does this. It’s just a metaphor derived from one instance of the model (of how human height regresses to the mean despite hereditary factors).

Comment: What do you mean by "imply literally" and "indirect meaning"?

Comment: I've done my best to explain with the example but maybe I'm unable to convey what I mean any other way. Sorry.

Comment: The original *ass-backwards*...

Comment: 'When we use the term “preposterous”, are we trying to imply literally that something is backwards?' I doubt that many people, even those who use rather than read the word, have much idea about the Latin derivation. The metaphor involved is a dead one.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: You mean bass-ackwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=preposterous&utm_source=extension_submit) explains very helpfully what it means both literally and figuratively:

> 1540s, "***contrary to nature, reason, or common sense***," from Latin
> ***praeposterus*** "absurd, contrary to nature, inverted, perverted, ***in
> reverse order***," **literally "before-behind"** (compare *topsy-turvy*, *cart
> before the horse*), from ***prae*** "*before*" + ***posterus***
> "*subsequent, coming after*," from ***post*** "after".
>
> The sense gradually shaded into "***foolish, ridiculous, stupid, absurd***."
> *The **literal meaning** "reversed in order or arrangement, having that
> last which ought to be first" (1550s) **is now obsolete** in English*.

In a way you are right, it can mean backwards in the sense of *'the wrong way'*, *not in the natural order of things*, and all this IS included in the meaning of ***absurd*** (see definitions of [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absurd) and [Dict.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/absurd)). But as Etymonline says, it is now only metaphorically used.